# How to fill 'extradata' field of AVCodecContext with SPS and PPS data?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

Here is the problem:  When decoding H264 stream with `ffmpeg`, I can obtain raw data of SPS and PPS but I have no idea how to fill them into the `extradata` field of `AVCodecContext`.  Without `extradata`, I can't decode frames properly.  Every time I call `avcodec_decodec_video2`, the return value is positive but the `got_picture` flag is always `zero`.

The stream I am dealing with looks like this:

```
[0x67]...[0x68]...[0x61]...[0x61]...  .......  [0x61]...[0x67]...[0x68]...  ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you mentioned is a byte stream holding NAL units for SPS and PPS. `extradata` in turn expects a pointer to AVC decoder configuration record, which is the data you have with extra formatting.

See MPEG-4 Part 15 "Advanced Video Coding (AVC) file format" section 5.2.4.1 for details.

```
5.2.4.1.1 Syntax 

aligned(8) class AVCDecoderConfigurationRecord { 
   unsigned int(8) configurationVersion = 1; 
   unsigned int(8) AVCProfileIndication; 
   unsigned int(8) profile_compatibility; 
   unsigned int(8) AVCLevelIndication;  
   bit(6) reserved = ‘111111’b;
   unsigned int(2) lengthSizeMinusOne;  
   bit(3) reserved = ‘111’b;
   unsigned int(5) numOfSequenceParameterSets; 
   for (i=0; i< numOfSequenceParameterSets;  i++) { 
      unsigned int(16) sequenceParameterSetLength ; 
  bit(8*sequenceParameterSetLength) sequenceParameterSetNALUnit; 
 } 
   unsigned int(8) numOfPictureParameterSets; 
   for (i=0; i< numOfPictureParameterSets;  i++) { 
  unsigned int(16) pictureParameterSetLength; 
  bit(8*pictureParameterSetLength) pictureParameterSetNALUnit; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!   Can I understand you in this way:  First, I should allocate some memory spaces which contain information that follow the AVC Decoder order.  Then let extradata point to this area?However, I wander how can I obtain the value of some parameters like "AVCProfileIndication"?  Are there appropriate functions I can use?

Comment: Correct. Profile and level values can be parsed right from SPS NAL unit you already have in your byte stream.

Answer (score -1):

```
c_v->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(flvBufSize + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
if(!c_v->extradata){
    loge("Could not av_malloc extradata");
}
logv("extradata_size =%d", c_v->extradata_size);
c_v->extradata_size = flvBufSize;
memcpy(c_v->extradata, avpkt.data, avpkt.size);

if (avcodec_open2(c_v, codec_v, NULL) < 0) {
    loge("could not open video codec");                             
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Do you need to run `avcodec_open2` for every AVPacket?

Comment: I don't understand where you get avpkt?