# FFMPEG C Library: Encoding h264 stream into Matroska .mkv container creates corrupt files

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, matroska

I want to use the FFMPEG C Library to create a Matroska Video .mkv file with only an h264 stream, but the resulting .mkv file comes out corrupt.

The file cannot be played back with Windows Media Player, ffplay, or VLC, and when I try to `ffprobe` the resulting file, these are the error messages:

```
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] No start code is found.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
# [...]
# this continues for a long time
```

I have followed the other troubleshooting steps for encoding h264 into Matroska, but none of them seemed to have done the trick for me:

- Setting `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER`: [Invalid data when creating mkv container with h264 stream because extradata is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278773/invalid-data-when-creating-mkv-container-with-h264-stream-because-extradata-is-n)
- Allocating some space for extradata: [Initializing an output file for muxing mkv with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620131/initializing-an-output-file-for-muxing-mkv-with-ffmpeg)

This is my C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

int main(void) {
    char *out_file_path = "./video.mkv";
    AVFormatContext *format_context;
    AVStream *video_stream;
    AVCodecContext *codec_context;

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&format_context, NULL, NULL, out_file_path);

    const AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    video_stream = avformat_new_stream(format_context, NULL);

    codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    av_opt_set(codec_context->priv_data, "preset", "superfast", 0);
    av_opt_set(codec_context->priv_data, "crf", "22", 0);

    codec_context->width = 1920;
    codec_context->height = 1080;
    codec_context->time_base = av_make_q(1, 30);
    codec_context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (strncmp("./video.mkv", out_file_path, 11) == 0) {
      printf("Writing .mkv...\n");
      codec_context->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
      codec_context->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_mallocz(1024 * 1024);
      codec_context->extradata_size = 1024 * 1024;
    } else {
      printf("Writing .mp4...\n");
    }

    // XXX avcodec_parameters_from_context is potentially superfluous (?)
    int ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(video_stream->codecpar, codec_context);

    ret = avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, NULL);

    avio_open(&format_context->pb, out_file_path, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);

    ret = avformat_write_header(format_context, NULL);

    // create a black input frame
    AVFrame *input_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    input_frame->width = 1920;
    input_frame->height = 1080;
    input_frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    ret = av_image_alloc(input_frame->data, input_frame->linesize, input_frame->width, input_frame->height, input_frame->format, 32);
    ptrdiff_t linesize[4] = { input_frame->linesize[0], input_frame->linesize[1], input_frame->linesize[2], input_frame->linesize[3] };
    ret = av_image_fill_black(input_frame->data, linesize, input_frame->format, 0, 1920, 1080);

    // write 2 seconds of video, all black
    for (size_t current_pts = 0; current_pts < 60; current_pts++) {
      input_frame->pts = av_rescale_q(current_pts, av_make_q(1, 30), codec_context->time_base);;

      ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, input_frame);

      AVPacket* packet = av_packet_alloc();

      while (1) {
          ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, packet);
          if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
              break;
          } else if (ret < 0) {
              printf("avcodec_receive_packet failed");
          } else {
              av_packet_rescale_ts(packet, codec_context->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
              ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(format_context, packet);
          }
      }

      av_packet_free(&packet);
    }

    av_frame_free(&input_frame);

    // flush encoder
    avcodec_send_frame(codec_context, NULL);
    AVPacket *flush_packet = av_packet_alloc();
    while (avcodec_receive_packet(codec_context, flush_packet) != AVERROR_EOF) {
        //int ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(format_context_, packet);
        av_packet_rescale_ts(flush_packet, codec_context->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
        ret = av_write_frame(format_context, flush_packet);
    }
    av_packet_free(&flush_packet);

    ret = av_write_trailer(format_context);
    ret = avio_close(format_context->pb);

    return 0;
}
```

The error handling is stripped out, but it does not raise any errors.

This code works when I write into an mp4 file, but creates a corrupt file when writing into .mkv. You can change the output container format to mp4 by setting
`char *out_file_path = "./video.mp4";`

You can compile this by running

```
clang -I$(FFMPEG_DIR)/include -L$(FFMPEG_DIR)/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil main.c -o makemkv
```

The output I’m getting while the above code is running:

```
Writing .mkv...
[libx264 @ 0x139804c40] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x139804c40] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x139804c40] 264 - core 164 r3108 31e19f9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2023 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x3 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=22.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=1:1.00
```

When I use the ffmpeg CLI, I can create a working .mkv from my working .mp4 like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v copy created-with-ffmpeg-cli.mkv
```

I have uploaded the resulting video files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FS-0fBAwKBbO-tyxC0VrFqcCyyqd0BR_?usp=sharing

Comment: @TedLyngmo I misunderstood how the tagging system should be used, I removed the tag now.

Comment: Ok. I added the c++ tag or else I don't think you'll get many readers :-)

Comment: Just a thought (doubt that it's the actual problem), you configured GOP to 1, essentially, converting H264 to MJPEG. Perhaps this causes some confusion?

Comment: Please post all your code why is there an RGB frame and swscale when U Just try to mux an h264 juv Stream Into a mkv Container ? The output from Decoder says there are no nal units eg no h264 Data Like SPS,PPS etc

Comment: @MarvinKilling **(1)** Does the command line version work okay with exact same H264 input to make a working MKV? **(2)** From the C++ code, does the output MKV have a smaller size than the input H264 data? Just wondering if a container is being setup correctly but then somehow the frame data was not _actually_ written. **(3)** Can you make a test file to share for our own playback testing? A simple 64x64 colour square is enough. Please encode that image into h264 (will be one frame) then mux with your code. Share 3 files: (a) the H264 itself, (b) as muxed into MKV, and (c) as muxed into MP4.

Comment: @MarvinKilling PS: If you can do the above **third point** it will be faster to get an answer, about the problem in output file data, from others who can check that same output. PPS: Are you open to advice/answers about manually muxing the H264 into MKV? I mean which is a higher priority for you in this task? Is it about learning correct FFmpeg usage in C++? Or else you just want to know how to deliver an MKV with H264 bytes yesterday (willing to write custom code)?

Comment: Hey, thanks everybody so far! I have rewritten my code above to be a complete example in plain C (not C++ anymore) and have uploaded the video files that it produces to Google Drive.

The interesting thing is still that creating an .mp4 with almost the same h264 stream configuration works. I’m pretty sure the issue is caused by this code:

`codec_context->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER; codec_context->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_mallocz(1024 * 1024); codec_context->extradata_size = 1024 * 1024;`

If I leave that out however, `avformat_write_header` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be this line:

```c
codec_context->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
```

If you remove it, everything works fine.

It is important to allocate some space yourself for extradata like this:

```
codec_context->extradata = (uint8_t*)av_mallocz(32);
codec_context->extradata_size = 32;
```

You must zero the extradata (e.g. by allocating it with `av_mallocz`) and make sure that its size is 6 or greater. The actual size does not seem to matter as long as it is 6 or greater.

This is different from writing into an mp4 container, where the extradata does not seem to matter.

Comment: I cannot see why this line correlates with 0 written in `pts`.  Does MKV spec explicitly require `AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER` and extended metadata?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] No start code is found.
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] decode_slice_header error
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] no frame!
> [h264 @ 0000015060d8f5c0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
> Last message repeated 1 times
> ```

It seems that your H.264 encoder does not set up keyframes with these settings. Please study the example code here: https://ffmpeg.org//doxygen/trunk/encode_video_8c-example.html

### Fix Data Types:

I am worried about this line:

```cpp
codec_context_->time_base = av_make_q(1, 90000);
```

Why don't you use `AVRational` type as it is suggested by the documentation?

```cpp
time_base = (AVRational){1, 25};
framerate = (AVRational){25, 1};
```

There are no obstacles to see whether your framerate seems constant.

For lossy H.264 the GOP size would be bigger than 1:

```cpp
    c->gop_size = 10;
    c->max_b_frames = 1;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
```

### Fix Timestamps:

My biggest concern here is that you **never increase** the `pts` field, so every frame in the sequence should have an identical timestamp as [`av_packet_rescale_ts`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__packet.html#gae5c86e4d93f6e7aa62ef2c60763ea67e) function only scales up the **valid** timestamp but it does not increment or recalculate it. So, all the frames have a timestamp 0 because it was never set up according to the existing framerate.

Comment: Hi, sorry if my code posted above caused misunderstandings. I did set up the pts & time bases correctly, the code worked without problems to create an h264 stream in an mp4 container.

`av_make_q` returns an AVRational and should be equivalent. The `time_base` was selected because of the use case of my code, the incoming frames have microsecond timestamps and might otherwise overlap. But this is not relevant for this problem.

I have now condensed my code to a minimal reproducible example and removed the unintuitive parts.